# MVC3 Aspose error on LoadData

Tags: loaddata, aspose-cells

I have an MVC3 C#.Net web app.  I am using the Aspose library to read an Excel file using the WorkBook.LoadData() method. I am able to Load a file from my local machine when running in Visual Studio.  I am able to load a file from the web server when running the web site.  However, when running the website, I cannot load an Excel file from my local machine.  I get the following error

```
"Unable to open specified Excel Workbook: Could not find a part of the path"
```

When I grab the path it says it can't fins and use my "Run" command...it finds the file.  So, it must be a permissions issue.  I am sure there is a simple fix but I don't know what it would be.  Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I suspected, it was a permissions issue.  It was not an Aspose issue.  I used the MS Interop library to run ImpersonateUser() using a service account that has access to the external machines